# Magento 2 Admin order's shipping method update event or plugin?

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

I want to do some functionality on update order's shipping method in admin so how it is possible. is there any event or plugin or other ?

Comment: are you looking for admin side shipping method list or when any particular method select?

Comment: Yes, I am updating in admin order.

Comment: My question, do you want event for when shipping method list is prepare? Or When any one select any shipping method from that list?

Comment: Whenever update the shipping method in admin order that time i want to execute  some custom functionality